# Proof polynomial is always divisible by number

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, divisibility

Given $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z} [x] $ a polynomial, that evaluated in any $a \in \mathbb{N} $, results always in a multiple of 101 or a multiple of 107 (both prime numbers). Prove then, that $f(x)$ is always divisible by 101 for all the values of $a$, or $f(x)$ is always divisible by 107 for all $a$.

Any suggestions on how should I start?

Comment: [What should I do if I don't know where to start?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599334/what-should-i-do-if-i-dont-know-where-to-start/599335#599335)

Comment: I'm stunned: it says that $\;f(a)\;$ is always divisible by $\;101\;$ or by $\;107\;$ , and then it asks to prove...this! Am I missing something here?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I think he has $f(a)=0(mod 101\times 107)$ and wants to prove $f(a)=0(mod 101)$ and $f(a)=0(mod 107)$.

Comment: exactly, sorry that might have been lost in my translation

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure, @Michael : it says "multiple of 101 **or** multiple of 107" ...Perhaps the OP means that under the assumption that an integer polynomial is always divisible either by one prime or by *other* prime then in fact it is **always** divisible by *only* one of those primes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $f(a)$ is divisible by either $101$ or $107$ for each $a\in\Bbb{Z}$, then $f(a)$ is divisible by at least one of them for all $a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409081/if-fa-is-divisible-by-either-101-or-107-for-each-a-in-bbbz-then-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very valuable hypothesis that $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$: the coefficients are integers (if this were not given you could only prove them to be rational). This allows reducing the polynomial itself modulo any number$~n$, and conclude that the evaluated polynomial $f(k)$ modulo$~n$ depends only on the congruence class of the value$~k$ (at which it was evaluated) modulo$~n$. Now for a proof by contradiction assume $f(k)$ is not divisible by$~107$ and $f(l)$ is not divisible by$~101$. Using that $107$ and $101$ are relatively prime (which is all that matters here), can you find a value to evaluate at the will give a contradiction?

Comment: I'm not seeing it right now. By intuition, I suppose, $f(kl)$ will give a contradiction but i need to think it a little more, thanks.

Comment: No that's not it. Which values are certainly congruent to $f(k)$ modulo$~107$? Which values are certainly congruent to $f(l)$ modulo$~101$? Do these two sets intersect?